# mysql: trying to select items not sold

Tags: mysql

A newbie question, probably as much logic as it is Mysql...

I have a table of quotations made for various products, with an order date if quotation resulted in an order:

```
quoteID     product    sellPrice       orderDate
  1           apple       1.00          5-29-1983  
  2           pear        1.35            null
  3           pear        1.25          6-18-1983
  4           banana      1.25            null
```

I'm trying to pull products never sold. I know I can count the number of times each item has been quoted with count (distinct product), but this gives me `apple 1; pear 2; banana 1`. What I want instead is `Banana 0`, or perhaps more useful `apple 1,1; pear 2,1; banana 1,0`, to show quotes-to-orders ratio.

Any help on this would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use `not in` unless you know the data well, and know the [Dangers of Not In](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32175659)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a subselect and  not in

```
 select product from my_table 
 where product not in (select product from my_table where orderDate is not null)
```

Comment: What if the in clause results in a null for product. We talked about that a few days ago. These are unsafe

Comment: all the product have null order date .. all the product are not sold  ..

Comment: Are you sure that in his actual table that is the case, or are you assuming that `select product from my_table where orderDate is not null` won't contain a `null` for `product` ? Try never to use `not in` and learn from the past.

Comment: i'm looking at the sample provided by the question .. and proposed my answer  i'am used not in in seveal  .... query and never i have problme  if you don't like the mine .. post your answer if you prefer your way ..

Comment: It is your responsibility to point out the dangers of `not in`. If you use it, and don't mention it, I will. Over and out. Here it is again, maybe you will read it and tinker with it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32175659

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer scaisEdge and comments Drew. As predicted by Drew, the proposed answer with `"NOT IN"` did not work. I ended up joining a `"null order table"` with an `"order table"` and it seems to work well (see below). Comments on this approach or the details are welcome!

**Results:**
"product","orderdate","product","orderdate","countOrders"
"banana",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL

**Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM 
(select product, orderdate  from quotes 
where orderdate IS NULL
group by product) as t1
LEFT JOIN
(select product, orderdate, count(product) 'countOrders' from quotes 
where orderdate is NOT NULL
group by product) as t2
on t1.product=t2.product
where countOrders is NULL
```