# SQL: Select entries which don't have composite primary key in another table

Tags: mysql

So I have two tables which both have a composite primary key made from two columns. I want to find the entries in the first table that do NOT exist in the second table, always keeping in mind that my primary key is composited.

I know I have to use `NOT IN` but I'm not sure how to make it work with two primary keys. Essentially I want something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table2)
```

The `id` though is a composited primary key made of two columns, `id1` and `id2`.
Any ideas how to approach that?

EDIT: Taking into consideration the dangers of `NOT IN` I'll try to better describe what I need. 
Apart from selecting the entries not in the secondtable there are two more actions needed to be done in the same query:

- Select the column which is less than 5 which I assume can be done easily by using `AND t1.column <5`
- Inner join `table1` with a third table on `id1`, as I need a column from that table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you explain why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`not in` seems like it would be overcomplicating things - and, as per Drew's comment, potentially very dangerous and/or infuriating if anything within the parentheses can be `null`.

This seems like a textbook use of an `outer join`. Use a `left [outer] join` on the key's columns, and if they (or any other single non-`null`able column in the right-hand table) are found to be `null` after the join, that means there's no matching record having that composite key in the right-hand table.

```
select *
from
    t1
    inner join t3 on
        t1.whatever = t3.whatever
    left join t2 on
        t1.id1 = t2.id1 and
        t1.id2 = t2.id2
where
    t1.some_column < 5 and -- 'normal' where criteria
    t2.id1 is null;         -- no match for key in t2
```

Comment: The thing is I already had to do an INNER JOIN so doing a LEFT JOIN too in the same query would make it too complicated for me. Your solution is probably right, and thanks for your insight.

Comment: @user3484582 Then it would've been a good idea to include the other preconditions in your question. Feel free to update it, and I'll see whether I can answer it more specifically based on the improved info available.

Comment: If people go around using `not in` without mentioning [the dangers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32175659) (afterall, people here are new to it all), then yikes. Later, as it is part of their handy tool box, they spend countless hours debugging their code, or not knowing there is even a problem.

Comment: @Drew Excellent point. I now remember being bitten by that before and being very confused... Thanks for the addition and +1.

Comment: I see about the dangers. I edited my OP to describe what I need in my query. I really have no idea how to combine INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: @user3484582 I've edited my answer. The extra `inner join` on `t1` to the 3rd table should not present an issue, as long as you're happy with what it means for the `left join` to `t2`: the `inner join` conceptually filters down what is entered into the `left join`. As for the additional criterion you mentioned in `t1`, you're correct that it can just be added to the `where` clause. Let me know once you've been able to try these and whether they produce the right results!

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense, was easier than I though. Works perfectly!

Comment: @user3484582 Great, you're welcome and thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a row constructor along with `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
WHERE (id1, id2) NOT IN (SELECT id1, id2 FROM table2);
```