# SQL: How to join tables right?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE animals 
(
    animal_id   INT PRIMARY KEY,
    animal_name VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE zoos 
(
     zoo_id   INT PRIMARY KEY,
     zoo_name VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE zoo_has_animals 
(
     zoo_id    INT,
     animal_id INT
);
```

I need to get all empty zoos. I've tried to join them using the next script:

```
SELECT zoos.zoo_name
FROM zoos
LEFT JOIN zoo_has_animals ON zoos.zoo_id = zoo_has_animals.zoo_id;
```

But it returns all not empty zoos instead of required empty zoos. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: You want an OUTER LEFT JOIN. I always refer to [this diagram](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg), hope it helps.

Comment: @marc_s It's for `MySQL`.

Comment: Look up the concept of `IS NULL`, regardless of what platform you're using.

Comment: @Aaron He's already using a `LEFT JOIN`...

Comment: @Siyual I mentionned `OUTER`, however I'm not sure the term is right. The diagram gives the solution though, by adding a `IS NULL` check on the second's table jointure column.

Comment: @Aaron There's no such thing as a non-`OUTER` `LEFT JOIN`.  `LEFT JOIN` (as well as `RIGHT`) are `OUTER JOIN`s.

Comment: @JaydipJ it is more an issue of performance with your deleted answer than with [Dangers of Not In](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32175659). The correlated subquery would likely underperform the left join. As the op schema has a PK on the parent table, hopefully the schema is changed to **NOT NULL** in the intersect table. But atm a NULL *could* be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a `JOIN` at all:

```
SELECT z.zoo_name
FROM zoos as z
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM zoo_has_animals
                 WHERE zoo_id = z.zoo_id);
```

With a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT z.zoo_name
FROM zoos as z
LEFT JOIN zoo_has_animals as h
     ON z.zoo_id = h.zoo_id 
WHERE h.zoo_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: I see, but is it possible to do that via JOINs?

Comment: @Alex of course, and the answer was given on the comments. Anyway, updated my answer with a version of it