# Selecting users who were not sent newsletter

Tags: mysql

Trying to create a query to select users who were not emailed the newsletter when the batch times out. The mail_log table captures entries from 3 different mailing lists, and maintains the log for the past 4-5 weeks - in other words there should be multiple log entries for each subscriber.

I want to select all subscribers who were not emailed when the batch times out while sending.

```
mail_log
+--------+------------+-------------+------------+---------+
| log_id | send_date  | location_id | mailing_id | list_id |
+--------+------------+-------------+------------+---------+
location_id is which mailing list
mailing_id is the specific newsletter
list_id is the subscriber's id in the mailing list

mail_list 
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
| list_id | fname | lname | email |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I have tried this query:

```
SELECT mail_list.*
FROM mail_list
LEFT JOIN mail_log ON mail_log.list_id = mail_list.list_id
WHERE mail_log.send_date = '2016-07-12'
AND mail_log.location_id = '2'
AND mail_log.list_id IS NULL`
```

The query returns 0 results, but a successful query should return about 700 results.

Comment: Yea, a shameless advertisement opportunity for [Dangers of Not In](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32175659)

Comment: You also have to select `mail_log.*` as well  --

Comment: Change WHERE to AND. Change the final AND to WHERE

Comment: @Zak Why does he need to select them? All those columns will be `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `LEFT JOIN`, you have to put the restrictions on the child table into the `ON` clause. Otherwise, when you test those fields, you'll only match non-NULL rows, which contradicts the `AND mail_log.list_id IS NULL` test.

```
SELECT mail_list.*
FROM mail_list
LEFT JOIN mail_log ON mail_log.list_id = mail_list.list_id
    AND mail_log.send_date = '2016-07-12'
    AND mail_log.location_id = '2'
WHERE mail_log.list_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you. Right after I posted, I discovered this query works as well.
    SELECT * FROM mail_list WHERE list_id NOT IN (SELECT list_id FROM mail_log WHERE mailing_id='216')

Any feedback on which query is better?

Comment: Ordinary joins tend to be better than `WHERE IN (SELECT ...)` because they use indexes better. I don't know offhand about the relative performance of `WHERE NOT IN`. Benchmark them.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM mail_list WHERE list_id NOT IN (SELECT list_id FROM mail_log WHERE mailing_id='216')

is worse because with a NOT IN, no index will be used. Query with left join could use list_id, send_date AND location_id as possible indexes for the join.