# What is wrong with my sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to  select from two separate tables and also trying to left join a different table by two different ids.

I keep getting this error:

> #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'wp_term_taxonomy'

```
SELECT  wp_terms.name, 
    wp_terms.slug, 
    wp_ads_categories.seo_description
FROM wp_terms, wp_ads_categories
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_ads_categories.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
```

Comment: If there's something wrong you'd get an error, or you'd get unexpected results. Which is it?

Comment: What you get, any errors???

Comment: I updated the post, please have a look

Comment: You're joining with `wp_term_taxonomy` twice. Which one of them is it supposed to use in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Also, it's generally a bad idea to mix cross products with explicit JOIN syntax. Use `INNER JOIN` for `wp_ads_categories`.

Comment: And it's usually wrong to refer to a `LEFT JOIN`ed table in the `WHERE` clause. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38339343/selecting-users-who-were-not-sent-newsletter

Comment: I want to use the first one in the where clause, but i also need to get data from this table wp_ads_categories its connected by term_id

Comment: The error message is fairly self-explanatory, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a valid query. It can't be the query you want, because, like your own query, it's basically nonsensical. But we can't know what the query you actually want is at this stage...

```
SELECT t.name
     , t.slug
     , c.seo_description
  FROM wp_terms t
 CROSS
  JOIN wp_ads_categories c
  LEFT 
  JOIN wp_term_taxonomy x
    ON x.term_id = t.term_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN wp_term_taxonomy y
    ON y.term_id = c.term_id 
   AND y.taxonomy = 'product_cat';
```

The query is nonsensical because there is generally no point OUTER JOINing tables from which you select no columns.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create aliases if you intend to use the same table more than once in the same query. Your query should be.

```
SELECT  wp_terms.name, 
    wp_terms.slug, 
    wp_ads_categories.seo_description
FROM wp_terms, wp_ads_categories
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tax1 ON wp_terms.term_id = tax1.term_id
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tax2 ON wp_ads_categories.term_id = tax2.term_id
WHERE tax1.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
```

The where clause might also be like this. It depends on how you want the result set to be.

```
WHERE tax2.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
```

Comment: .. and the corresponding LEFT JOIN would then be an INNER JOIN

Comment: @Strawberry not necessarily right? Tables `wp_terms` and `wp_ads_categories` might have records which might not be present in table `wp_term_taxonomy ` for given join conditions. In such a case, if I need to fetch all records from `wp_terms` and `wp_ads_categories`, irrespective they being present in third table, I will have to put a left (outer) join.

Am I missing out something?

Comment: You're missing something. Either the JOIN is an INNER one, or the WHERE condition needs to move to the JOIN clause. This can be demonstrated by running EXPLAIN EXTENDED on a representative  query, followed by SHOW WARNINGS;

Comment: Yes you are right @Strawberry. By adding a where clause there is no purpose left to left (outer) join. The condition should be rather added in join on clause if we require a true outer join.