# Not IN operator in mysql returns NULL

Tags: mysql

```
                SELECT *
                FROM fabric_restock AS fabr
                LEFT JOIN fabric_po AS fabpo 
                ON fabpo.fab_id = fabr.fab_id
                WHERE 
                fabr.fab_id NOT IN (     
                SELECT fabpo.fab_id
                FROM 
                fabric_po fabpo
                WHERE
                fabpo.status <= 1
                AND 
                fabpo.fab_id IS NOT NULL
                )
                AND 
                fabr.restock_ten <= fabpo.qty
```

//THe complete query returns null when subquery returns no rows or returns nulls

How do I fix this?

It should instead return all the record from outer query when sub query returns no records

Edit: Original query:

```
                SELECT *
                FROM fabric_restock AS fabr
                LEFT JOIN fabric_po AS fabpo ON fabpo.fab_id = fabr.fab_id
                WHERE 
                fabr.fab_id NOT IN (
                SELECT fabpo.fab_id
                FROM 
                fabric_po fabpo
                JOIN 
                fabric_challan fabchallan
                ON 
                fabpo.po_num =  fabchallan.po_num
                WHERE
                fabchallan.challan_num 
                NOT IN (SELECT challan_num FROM fabric_grn)
                AND 
                fabpo.status <= 1
                )
                AND 
                fabr.restock_ten <= fabpo.qty
```

Sample data:

```
    # fab_id, fabric_mother_id, qty_mother, cluster, qty, cf_thirty, cf_ten, cf_three, cf_cluster, sellout_thirty, sellout_ten, sellout_three, num_good_sku, num_coll, num_collection_p, num_sale, new_cf, percentile, restock_thirty, restock_ten, restock_three, status, num_new, parent, lace_type, po_id, po_num, fab_id, vendor_code, color_code, qty, estimated_price, po_date, arrival_date, estimated_date, composition, material, type, inType, status, gsm, notes, image, approveStatus, approve_date, shrinkage, fabric_mother_id, qty_type, main_construction, place_order_date, width, vendor_comments, email_send, wash, brand
FAB1001, SBL104, 10.00, cluster, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 0, 10, 1, Washed, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 
FAB1002, SBL101, 20.00, cluster1, 20.00, 20.00, 20.00, 20.00, 20, 20.00, 20.00, 20.00, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20.00, 20.00, 20.00, 20.00, 20.00, 0, 20, 2, Bleached, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 
FAB1003, SBL102, 30.00, cluster2, 30.00, 30.00, 30.00, 30.00, 30, 30.00, 30.00, 30.00, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30.00, 30.00, 30.00, 30.00, 30.00, 0, 30, 3, RFD, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 
FAB1004, SBL103, 40.00, cluster3, 40.00, 40.00, 40.00, 40.00, 40, 40.00, 40.00, 40.00, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40.00, 40.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 0, 40, 4, Dyed, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
```

fabpo table: empty at the moment

Comment: Obligatory [Dangers of Not In](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32175659)

Comment: @Drew: I understand that but do not know how to replace this particular query with NOT EXISTS

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and the expected result? I guessed what you are trying to do, but now I am not too sure if I got it right

Comment: @Philipp: Need to filter out id's from fabricrestock table for which there are rows in fabricpo table and have their status <0. I had actually cut it short for the example sake. Updating question with entire query

Comment: Have you tried adding `fabpo.fab_id IS NOT NULL` to your subquery? You have it in the first example but not in the second

Comment: @Philipp: I tried that. It didn't change anything

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining onto an empty table. That is alright.

But later you are trying to compare a value from your table with the null field from the joined table, which does not work.

```
fabr.restock_ten <= fabpo.qty
```

> fabpo table: empty at the moment

I guess you could handle this situation by checking for null on fabpo.qty, though it is a little weird (maybe only because I don't really understand what all the columnnames mean).

```
AND (fabr.restock_ten <= fabpo.qty OR fabpo.qty IS NULL)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to bring up :) . That's correct. What should be the work around for that? I can't use restock_ten in the subquery and now turns out can't use fabpo.qty either . What should I do?

Comment: You could check for null, or you could use `fabr.restock_ten <= IFNULL(fabpo.qty, 0)` to turn the null into 0, but then you wouldn't get results too I guess (you could turn it to some very high value too, to get the results)