# Select from table where doesn't appear in another table PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have 2 tables, one called `system_dashboard_stats` (tbl1) and another called `user_dashboard_stats` (tbl2).  I want to display all rows from  tbl1 that dont appear in tbl2.

So far, from looking i've found the below code, however it doesnt seem to be working as I currently see all rows from the DB.

```
$result11=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM system_dashboard_stats WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM user_dashboard_stats)")or die('Error' . mysql_error());
```

Comment: show the schema for  the two table please

Comment: See [Dangers of NOT In](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32175659) in case it applies

Comment: update you question  and show the table columns name for both the tables

Comment: See our exciting documentation page [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/795/table-creation/9210/show-table-structure#t=201607232010391340802) that we so proudly present to everyone ... `show create table xyz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM system_dashboard_stats 
    LEFT JOIN user_dashboard_stats 
        ON system_dashboard_stats.pk = user_dashboard_stats.fk 
WHERE user_dashboard_stats.fk IS NULL;`

Answer (score 0):

You should write this

```
$result11=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM system_dashboard_stats LEFT JOIN user_dashboard_stats ON system_dashboard_stats.pk = user_dashboard_stats.fk WHERE user_dashboard_stats.fk IS NULL")or die('Error' . mysql_error());
```