# Deleting non referenced data from database

Tags: mysql, sql

Because of a bad design, I have to clean up a database. There's data in there which is not "connected" correctly (Foreign keys were not set) 
Therefore I want to delete all data which is not referenced.
I have created with a join a temporary table `temp1` and inserted all the `Entity_ID` which have no connection to the main table `entity`. The next step is, I want to delete from `entityisactive` all the bad data with following query:

```
Delete from db1.entityisactive where db1.entityisactive.Entity_ID IN
(
Select db1.temp1.Entity_ID from db1.temp1 
)
```

The Problem is, I get a connection time out, also when I do that`Select db1.temp1.Entity_ID from db1.temp1 where Entity_ID = 42`

What I want to do is delete all entries in `entityisactive` where `entityisactive.Entity_ID = temp1.Entity_ID`

How can I speed up the SQL-Query? Or where is my error in reasoning?

Comment: you can create indexes and use NOT IN but not that NOT IN can be wildly dangerous

Comment: Try to limit the number of results of the inner query, then run it multiple times until it deletes nothing: `Select db1.temp1.Entity_ID from db1.temp1 LIMIT 1000`

Comment: dangers of not in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32175659

Comment: @Drew the OP didn't ask about `NOT IN`

Comment: @alfasin I am cautioning its use

Comment: You could do an update with a join pattern after an alter table creating a new column. There a a ton of ways to do it

Comment: @Drew I can see that, only that it's not relevant to this question, only to your first comment.

Comment: I will let you mysql experts solve this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using an explicit `join` and then defining indexes.  The code would look like:

```
Delete eia
    from db1.entityisactive eia join
         db1.temp1 t
         on eia.Entity_ID = t.Entity_ID ;
```

Then, this query wants an index on either `temp1(Entity_Id)` or `entityisactive(Entity_Id)`.  Both indexes are not necessary and the second might have the better performance.

Comment: I have indexes on the `entityisactive` table. Tanks for the answer, it works perfect.