# SQL delete row where one value matches that a value in a DIFFERENT column

Tags: sql

I want to delete a row if a particular x value matches a y value in any row in the same table.

Ex:

```
| x | y |  
| 4 | 2 |  
| 2 | 6 |  
| 8 | 1 |  
| 3 | 1 |  
| 7 | 8 |  
| 9 | 5 |
```

would become:

```
| x | y |    
| 4 | 2 |  
| 3 | 1 |  
| 7 | 8 |  
| 9 | 5 |
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Which flavor of SQL are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Use `EXISTS`

```
Delete from 
yourtable where exists (select 1 from tab b where b.y =yourtable.x)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your DB allows it, a self-join may work:

```
DELETE FROM foo AS xside
LEFT JOIN foo AS yside ON xside.y = yside.x
```

Comment: Some RDBMS don't like the join being able to cause the row to be deleted more than once.  In which case a sub query, for yside, with a GROUP BY or a DISTINCT could help.

Comment: for mysql, this'd be the only way to do it. you can't do a (sub)select on a table you're modifying, but a join works.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `LEFT JOIN (subquery) AS yside`

Answer (score 1):

```
Delete from tab where x in ( select y from tab)
```

Alternate version to counter null values in `y` column.

```
Delete from tab t where exists ( select 1 from tab ta where ta.y = t.x)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175497/mysql-not-in-query-3-tables

Comment: @Matt - the `NULL` issue is, in my opinion, the strongest reason to avoid `IN`.  Some RDBMS optimise better than others, but all will bite you int he list is NULLable.

Comment: @Matt thanks for your observation. Edited my answer to include alternate version of the query